# how to serialize ArrayBuffer into BSON object for websocket transfer in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, bson, arraybuffer

I want encode a **javascript object** with a **ArrayBuffer element** into `BSON` and transfer it over `websocket`.  However the serialized BSON object is 10 time bigger than it should be.

The code is something like this:

```
var A = {buffer: new ArrayBuffer(1024)};

bson_buffer_size = BSON.calculateObjectSize(A) // returns 9164, I am expecting ~1024
```

My understanding of BSON serializer must be wrong.  Does anyone know how I can create a compact BSON object with a binary buffer field?